# NestJS Queues @OnQueueCompleted

Tags: javascript, nestjs

Where does the result come from? I have tried from the "Process" method:

```
@Process('myProcess')
async handleMyProcess(job: Job) {
    
    return true;

}

@OnQueueCompleted()
async onCompleted(job: Job, result: any) {
    console.log(result); //<-- shouldn't this be true?
}
```

It's always `undefined`.

Thanks